# Code shows error in cluster but works fine otherwise

Tags: bash, cluster-computing

Hello everyone,
                  I have a bash file which has the following code:

```
 ./lda --num_topics 15 --alpha 0.1 --beta 0.01 --training_data_file testdata/test_data.txt --model_file Model_Files/lda_model_t15.txt --burn_in_iterations 120 --total_iterations 150
```

This works perfectly fine normally but when I run it in a cluster it is not loading the data that it is supposed to load from the connected .cc files. I have given #!/bin/bash in the header. What can I do to rectify this situation? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to mention the full path to the `lda` executable. Since it's not invoked by you manually, the system will not know where to find the executable if invoked by the shell. Since this is not a shell command, you don't necessarily need the `#!/bin/bash` even.

```
/<FullPath>/lda --num_topics 15 --alpha 0.1 --beta 0.01 --training_data_file testdata/test_data.txt --model_file Model_Files/lda_model_t15.txt --burn_in_iterations 120 --total_iterations 150
```